# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'buildFromTemplate' of undefined at HTMLButtonElement.getVideoSources

Tags: javascript, html, electron, desktop-application

i follow along with the tutorial from firespace which is a electron tutorial and i get this massage saying that was an error even though the tutorial doesn't

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'buildFromTemplate' of undefined
> at HTMLButtonElement.getVideoSources

```
const { writeFile } = require("fs");

const dialog = remote;
const Menu = remote;

// Global state
let mediaRecorder; // MediaRecorder instance to capture footage
const recordedChunks = [];

// Buttons
const videoElement = document.querySelector("video");

const startBtn = document.getElementById("startBtn");
startBtn.onclick = (e) => {
  mediaRecorder.start();
  startBtn.classList.add("is-danger");
  startBtn.innerText = "Recording";
};

const stopBtn = document.getElementById("stopBtn");

stopBtn.onclick = (e) => {
  mediaRecorder.stop();
  startBtn.classList.remove("is-danger");
  startBtn.innerText = "Start";
};

const videoSelectBtn = document.getElementById("videoSelectBtn");
videoSelectBtn.onclick = getVideoSources;

// Get the available video sources
async function getVideoSources() {
  const inputSources = await desktopCapturer.getSources({
    types: ["window", "screen"],
  });

  const videoOptionsMenu = Menu.buildFromTemplate(
    inputSources.map((source) => {
      return {
        label: source.name,
        click: () => selectSource(source),
      };
    })
  );

  videoOptionsMenu.popup();
}

// Change the videoSource window to record
async function selectSource(source) {
  videoSelectBtn.innerText = source.name;

  const constraints = {
    audio: false,
    video: {
      mandatory: {
        chromeMediaSource: "desktop",
        chromeMediaSourceId: source.id,
      },
    },
  };

  // Create a Stream
  const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints);

  // Preview the source in a video element
  videoElement.srcObject = stream;
  videoElement.play();

  // Create the Media Recorder
  const options = { mimeType: "video/webm; codecs=vp9" };
  mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream, options);

  // Register Event Handlers
  mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = handleDataAvailable;
  mediaRecorder.onstop = handleStop;

  // Updates the UI
}

// Captures all recorded chunks
function handleDataAvailable(e) {
  console.log("video data available");
  recordedChunks.push(e.data);
}

// Saves the video file on stop
async function handleStop(e) {
  const blob = new Blob(recordedChunks, {
    type: "video/webm; codecs=vp9",
  });

  const buffer = Buffer.from(await blob.arrayBuffer());

  const { filePath } = await dialog.showSaveDialog({
    buttonLabel: "Save video",
    defaultPath: `vid-${Date.now()}.webm`,
  });

  if (filePath) {
    writeFile(filePath, buffer, () => console.log("video saved successfully!"));
  }
}
```

This code is from the sourcefile from the tutorial github.

can you help or fix it, thank you

Comment: What is your electron version?

Comment: As you are consuming  `node_moduels` on your renderer. You should enable the `nodeIntegration: true` while creating the browserWindow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const {remote} = require("electron");
const {dialog, Menu} = remote;
```

not

```
const dialog = remote;
const Menu = remote;
```

And I believe you are using the newer version of Electron and you need to create BrowserWindow like this

```
const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true,
      enableRemoteModule: true
    }
  })
```

As you are not allowed to use `remote` on renderer as `enableRemoteModuel` is `false` by default from v9

Comment: i already use that code but the response change to

"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'dialog' of 'remote' as it is undefined.
    at render.js:5"

Comment: Have you enabled this nodeIntegration?

Comment: And you also need to set `enableRemoteModule: true` while creating browser window